# Live Logs in pytest omits some loggers

Tags: pytest

When I enable pytest [live logs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/logging.html#live-logs) using `--log-cli-level=INFO` I find that only *some* of the log messages are shown by the 'live log' output while pytest is running whereas some are missing (despite being written to a file handler).

It seems to be some loggers which are always shown, while others are completely invisible to pytest, why is this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that only logs which propagate up to the root logger (with name `''`) are captured by pytest.

I had a logger `foo` configured with `'propagate': False` (and its own handlers) which means all `foo.X` loggers were not shown by pytest live logs.

You can either change it to propagate, or if you wish to keep propagate=False in production but still make live logs work during tests you can modify it in `pytest_configure` in `conftest.py`:

```py
logger = logging.getLogger('foo')
# The crucial part is to allow propagation up to the root logger
logger.propagate = True
# This is helpful if the same handler is also present on the root logger, to avoid duplicates during tests
logger.handlers = []
```